# matlab: running fft on short time intervals in a for-loop for the length of data

Tags: matlab, for-loop, fft

I have some EEG data that I would like to break down into 30-second windows and run a fast Fourier transform on each window of data. I've tried to implement a for-loop and increment the index value by the number of samples in the time window. When I run this, I can see that (1) this works for the first window of data, but not the rest of them  because (I think) the "number of samples minus one" leads to fewer elements than necessary for data_fft and thus doesn't have the same dimensions as f, which are both being plotted in a figure. (2) I tried to update the index value by adding the number of samples in a window, but after i = 1, it goes to i = 2 in my workspace and not to i = 7681 as I'd hoped. I've spent an embarrassingly long time on trying to figure out how to change this so it works correctly, so any advice is appreciated! Code is below. Let me know if I can clarify anything.

```
    data_ch6 = data(:,6); % looking at just 1 electrode

    tmax = 2*60; % total time in sec I want to analyze; just keeping it to 2 minutes for this exercise 
    tmax_window = 30;  %30 sec window
    times = tmax/tmax_window; % number of times fft should be run
    Nsamps = tmax*hdr.SPR; % total # samples in tmax; sample rate is 256 hz
    Nsamps_window = tmax_window*hdr.SPR; % # samples in time window
    f = hdr.SPR*(0:((Nsamps_window-1)/2))/Nsamps_window; % frequency for plotting


    for i = 1:Nsamps;   % need to loop through data in 30 second windows in tmax
        data_fft = abs(fft(data_ch6(i:i+Nsamps_window-1))); %run fft on data window
        data_fft = data_fft(i:((i+Nsamps_window-1)/2)); %discard half the points

        figure
        plot(f, data_fft)
        i = i+Nsamps_window;

    end
```

Comment: Why not use `Spectrogram`?

Comment: This is just an exercise I've created for myself since I'll have to do FFTs over long periods of data eventually. My problem is even more "basic" than "how do I run an FFT", I think it has to do more with how to construct a for-loop correctly for this type of situation where I want to increment by a certain number of points, and I want to know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few things that are wrong in your code. First, let me start be saying that `i` is a very poor choice for a variable name since in matlab it usually stand for `sqrt{-1}`.
As for your code, I assume that you intend to perform windowed FFT without overlapping.

1) Your loop goes from 1 to `Nsamps` with an increment of 1. That means the each time you advance 1 sample. In other words you have `Nsamps_window-1` overlap. You can use perhaps `i=1:Nsamps_window:Nsamps-Nsamps_window-1` if you are not interested in overlapping.

2) The length of `data_fft` is `Nsamps_window`, so I think what you wanted to do is  `data_fft = data_fft(1:round(Nsamps_window/2));`

3) When plotting FFT results, I suggest using dB: `plot(20*log10(abs(data_fft)));`

4) The line `i = i+Nsamps_window;` is meaningless since `i` is your loop variable (it has not effect).